# How to parse public key from a text file containing more than the key

Tags: c++, parsing, openssl

I have a set of public and private keys that I want to use in my code. Both keys are stored in files, but the public key is stored in a text file in which the first line has "id : {a number}" and then from line two starts tha public key.

I tried to write a function to parse the file and return an RSA pointer (RSA *). It works by reading the first line of the file and ignoring it, just to move the file pointer, and then I use `pub_key=PEM_read_RSAPublicKey(fp,NULL,NULL,NULL);` to fill pub_key and return it.

This is my function call `pub_key = parse_pubkey_from_common_file("encryption/1.id");` and this is my function:

```
RSA *parse_pubkey_from_common_file(char *filepath)
{
RSA *pub_key=NULL;
FILE *fp=NULL;
size_t len = 0;
size_t nread = 0;

char *line = NULL;
fp = fopen(filepath, "rt");
bool first=true;

while ((int)(nread = getline(&line, &len, fp)) != -1)
{
    line[nread-1] = '\0';   //  get rid of the "\n"
    std::cout << "line = " <<line << "length = "<<nread<< std::endl;
    if (first)
        break;      
}

free(line);
pub_key = PEM_read_RSAPublicKey(fp,NULL,NULL,NULL);
if (pub_key!=NULL)
{
    fprintf(stderr,"Public key read.\n");
}

BIO * keybio = BIO_new(BIO_s_mem());
RSA_print(keybio, pub_key, 0);
char buffer [1024];
std::string res = "";
while (BIO_read (keybio, buffer, 1024) > 0)
{
    std::cout << buffer;
}
BIO_free(keybio); //appropriate free "method"
fclose(fp);
std::cout << "------------------ from the original file ------------------" << '\n';
fp = fopen("encryption/public.pem", "rt");
pub_key = PEM_read_RSAPublicKey(fp,NULL,NULL,NULL);
if (pub_key!=NULL)
{
    fprintf(stderr,"Public key read.\n");
}

keybio = BIO_new(BIO_s_mem());
RSA_print(keybio, pub_key, 0);
res = "";
while (BIO_read (keybio, buffer, 1024) > 0)
{
    std::cout << buffer;
}
BIO_free(keybio); //appropriate free "method"

unsigned int cipher_size=RSA_size(pub_key);
std::cout << "cipher_size is: "<< cipher_size << '\n';
fclose(fp);

return pub_key;
}
```

From "std::cout ---- from the original file -----" and below is code that does the same thing but with the original (.pem) file with the public key.

When I run the function with this part commented out I can not use correctly the returned RSA *. But when this runs and overwrites the above variable, I can use it correctly later with no problems.

I also tried to print what I read to find any differences but there were not any.

Here are the files I use and a screenshot of the execution:

the first file accessed during the execution with id: {a number} in it
[image: first screenshot]

the second file un-edited .pem, with the public key:
[image: second screenshot]

last, the execution output:
[image: third screenshot]

It might be something obvious that I miss but, I cannot figure out why this happens.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: I don't see any difference between your two loading routines and they both should work the same.  So I think there must be something else going on.